# Loopback address changes to public address automatically

Tags: networking

I got a strange problem today.

When I type 127.0.0.1 in the browser it automatically changes back to the public address.

Can anyone please tell me what could be the possible issue ?

Comment: How about moer info...what browser, OS, ANYTHING else?

Comment: It is a Windows machine, the behavior is same in both Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a problem with your name resolution. 
Try flushing DNS cache by

- Start -> Run -> type cmd
- in command prompt, type ipconfig /flushdns

If it works cool!, else please provide following information:

What is the response of browser to "localhost".

What are the contents of C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you got HTTP redirect from server on 127.0.0.1. You could use Chrome **Network** tab (**Tools** -> **Developer Tools**) to check server response.